# How to exclude rows that meet a criteria based on one row's value in activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using ActiveAdmin and have this scope that shows orders with expiring subscriptions:

```
scope: expired do |orders|
  orders
    .joins(:subscriptions)
    .group('orders.id')
    .having('MIN(subscriptions.end_date) < ?', Time.now.end_of_day)
```

And I have orders setup where they can have multiple subscriptions, so if one subscription is expired, and one is not, then this scope will still show that order.

So in this case, I have something a set of results like this 
that returns something like this:

[image]

and say the date is 2/24/19, I'd like to be able to exclude all rows with an ID of 14010497 since not all the subscriptions have expired. How would I do this in activerecord? I tried using `NOT IN` like so:

`where('orders.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id from distributions WHERE distributions.end_date < ?)'` but I think I am using in incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
scope: expired do |orders|
  orders
    .joins(:subscriptions)
    .group('orders.id')
    .where('subscription.end_date < ?', Time.now.end_of_day)
    .having('count(subscriptions.id) = ?', 0)
end
```

Will give expired orders which has all expired subscriptions